# Prestashop redirects itself to web root

Tags: php, prestashop

I got copy of working e-shop built on prestashop. When I run it on localhost (localhost/tretry/web/cs/),  it show me file from another web (localhost/index.php). Adress stays the same (localhost/tretry/web/cs/).
What settings/file could possibly do that? How to redirect it back?

I changed shop url in database according to settings from clean prestashop instalation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete the `.htaccess` file (there's no need to regenerate it).
2. Change your URL setup to match this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was Friendly URL issue.
I do not have enough reputation to vote up, pittz :(

Comment: Glad to have been of help! :)

Comment: I have nearly the same problem. Downloaded existing shop, when i go to localhost/shop it redirects to www.theexistingshop.com
I can't access the admin page so how to do that ? In SQL table configuration, domain and domain_SSL are set to localhost already as they were in the online website

Comment: @Rayjax: Please post that as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Answer (score 1):

**For migrating to another host, follow the steps below :**

1. Go to the phpMyAdmin panel and export the entire database as a SQL file.
2. Upload the files to the new FTP or local system.
3. Change the settings in /config/settings.inc.php and update:

   ```
   define('_DB_SERVER_', '');
   define('_DB_NAME_', '');
   define('_DB_USER_', '');
   define('_DB_PASSWD_', '');
   ```
4. Go to phpMyAdmin of your new site and import the **SQL** file.
5. Search for the following tables and update the store location:

   ```
   Table: ps_configuration
   Fields:
   PS_SHOP_DOMAIN : www.yourdomain.com
   PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL : www.yourdomain.com
   Table: ps_shop_url
   Fields:
   domain:www.yourdomain.com
   domain_ssl: www.yourdomain.com
   physical_uri: / (slash for root or /folder/ location of prestashop)
   ```